# How to hear DTMF tones when call in progress and than established in Android using SINCH VOIP SDK

Tags: sinch

I wish to send DTMF sound to the calling user when call in progress so that user can know that call is in progress. Please provide your comments as I am not able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Hi you don't send DTMF to play progress tone, what you can do is you can play a local file (sample file is provided in the SDK downloads) until you get a Calldidprogress, then we will play that progress. If you don't get a callDidProgress you will get callEstablished so make sure you stop that local file there as well.

Comment: I have the sdk but cant understand how to play the sound using which function. Can you please provide some code snippet ?

Comment: - (id<SINAudioController>)audioController {
  return [[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] client] audioController];
}
    [[self audioController] startPlayingSoundFile:[self pathForSound:@"incoming.wav"] loop:YES];